# css nth-child exclusive to the document

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

So when you use `.class:nth-child(2)` it will affect all the second instances of that class in the document...I want it to only affect the first instance. Let me explain:

`.content:nth-child(2)` will affect the contents with the attribute affected

```
<div class="test">
    <div class="content">a</div>
    <div class="content" affected="true">a</div>
    <div class="content">a</div>
    <div class="content">a</div>
</div>
<div class="test">
    <div class="content">a</div>
    <div class="content" affected="true">a</div>
    <div class="content">a</div>
    <div class="content">a</div>
</div>
```

## [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r3bSz/)

My question, is how can I set it to only affect the first instance of the nth-child, as in the second `.content` in the entire document rather than all the second `.contents` in any div?

Comment: .test:nth-child(1) .content:nth-child(2){
    background-color:#f00;
} but i guess its not acceptable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could apply it to the second div, which has to be identified in a unique way

http://jsfiddle.net/r3bSz/1/

```
#test >.content:nth-child(2){
 background-color:#f00;
}
```

There are multiple ways to achieve this. You could, for example, go with the first child (`:first-child` or `:nth-child(1)`), too.

Comment: If you use an `id`, then this would be enough: `#test .content:nth-child(2)` or doesnt it?

Comment: Yes you are right, it would be enough. However, i think that it is clearer that way and more safe against changes in the HTML structure.

Answer (score 1):

You mean that you only want to affect the *second div.conent* in the *first d.test*?

```
.test:first-child .content:nth-child(2){
    background-color:#f00;
}
```

Hope I understand correctly.